# Python - changing object attributes initialised from dictionary affects the original dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a class with attributes initialised based on a user-defined dictionary (read in using JSON):

```
class Knight(object):
    def __init__(self, traits):
        for k, v in traits.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)

traitfile = json.load(open(input(), 'r'))
# Where the input file is e.g. 
# {'helmet': 'horned', 
#  'sword': 'big', 
#  'words': ['Ni!', 'Peng', 'Neee-Wom!']}
```

When I instantiate the object, `helmet`, `sword`, and `words` become attributes as expected. But if I then change an instance attribute, it seems like it affects the original dictionary from which the object was initialised in the first place:

```
tall_knight = Knight(traitfile)

print(tall_knight.words) # prints ['Ni!', 'Peng', 'Neee-Wom!']
print(traitfile['words']) # also prints ['Ni!', 'Peng', 'Neee-Wom!']

tall_knight.words.append('Ekke ekke!')

print(tall_knight.words) # prints ['Ni!', 'Peng', 'Neee-Wom!', 'Ekke ekke!'] as expected
print(traitfile['words']) # also prints ['Ni!', 'Peng', 'Neee-Wom!', 'Ekke ekke!'] NOT EXPECTED
```

I did not expect the change to the object's attribute would affect the dictionary it was initialised from. I thought the whole point of instantiation is that the instance is, well, its own instance! What is going on here?! (And how can I stop it?)

Comment: list/dict keep other lists/dicts as reference and when you copy to other list/dict then you doesn't duplicate them but only copy reference to the same object - and it has nothing to do with Class instantiation. You may need to use `copy.copy(...)` or even `copy.deepcopy(...)` if it has other nested lsits/dicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `traitfile['words']` is a list, and when you copy it to `tall_knight.words`, you are copying a reference to the list, not the values in it. So when you modify the list in `tall_knight`, you also modify the value in `traitfile['words']`. You can work around this by making a copy of the value in the object using [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy%20copy#copy.copy) (or `copy.deepcopy` if the values may be nested):

```
import copy()

class Knight(object):
    def __init__(self, traits):
        for k, v in traits.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, copy.copy(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

As list is mutable object in python so when you create an object the reference would be the same behind the scene so you need to call the list.copy() which will create a copy with different reference then your changes will not reflect in the original one.

```
first_list = {"a":1, "b":[2,3,4]}
second_list = first_list
second_list["b"].append(34)
print("first one: ", first_list)
print("second one: ", second_list)
```

Output:

```
 first one:  {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4, 34]}
 second one:  {'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4, 34]}
```

So the better to avoid the changes into the original one is to use the copy function: second_list = first_list.copy()

Including more as per your case you also need to create the copy before  changing the object:

```
import copy
    class Knight(object):
    def __init__(self, traits):
        for k, v in traits.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, copy.deepcopy(v))

traitfile = json.load(open(input(), 'r'))
```

Here is the link for reference: [Mutable and Immutable datatypes](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a)